# GE dimmer works with 3 LED lights, somewhat with 4 and not at all with 5

Tags: led, dimmer-switch

I've got a brand new single pole GE 14294 Z-Wave Plus dimmer.  Before I try to connect it to z-wave, I wanted to make sure it was working.  I have five LED lights (4W, 65mA, BR20 flood) lights in series.  They were dimming fine on my old Leviton dimmer so I know they are OK.

Using the switch itself, the dimmer will switch the lights on and off no problem, but will not dim. BUT, if I unscrew two bulbs, then the remaining three work fine - i.e., the dimmer works correctly.  If I add the 4th back in, the will dim slightly.

I've checked the current, and 3 lights are pulling about 0.2A.  With four that goes up to 0.26A, with five about 0.32A.  Switch is rated for 1500W and is compatible with LED.

I've tried a different 14294 and have exactly the same problem.  Note that at this stage I'm just using the physical switch, so nothing to do with z-wave.

Any ideas?  Bug in the firmware?  Could it be the bulbs? 
I Called Jasco/GE and they didn't know.

Comment: What make and model are the bulbs?

Comment: What is the power factor of the bulbs?

Comment: Screw one incandescent bulb in (with 4 LED bulbs) and test. What happens?    Also you probably don’t mean “in series”, if they are in fact in a series circuit fix that first.

Comment: @Tyson - correct - my bad.  Not in series.

Comment: @Harper - will measure and let you know.

Comment: The reason for one incandescent as part of a test is it increases the load.  Your scenario is a little different than most having a compatibility issue, but there is a minimum wattage issue that often shows up....

Comment: @harper - I've tried two different LED bulbs in a test setup, along with an incandescent (i,e., outlet->dimmer>killawatt->bulb).  PF on both LEDs was 0.96.  Leviton dimmer takes PF down to about 0.6 when fully dimmed - but bulbs are still relatively bright, though dimmed.  GE dimmer does nothing.  PF stays at 0.96 and no dimming happens.

Incandescent behaves as expected - both dimmers work fine, taking bulb through full range of brightness.

Seems like the GE dimmer really doesn't like the LEDs.  Faulty dimmer?

Comment: Weird that it works on 3 bulbs, but not on 4, 5 or 1!!

Answer (score -1):

I think this has todo with minimum load. These dimmers require 50 watt min

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You should improve this answer because as it stands it is being flagged as low quality and is in danger of being deleted. I would suggest as a minimum if you could support the claim of the minimum load by taking a snapshot of the spec sheet for the switch that shows this data and explain what that means.

Comment: And, if this is true, then why do things start going wrong when the OP adds load to a working system?

Answer (score -1):

I’m having similar issues, and looked in page one of the manual and it says for incandescent lighting only. Not impressed!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good answer, but is this the same model as the OP? Would you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Based on the manual available online @ zwave.eu for the GE 14294, this doesn't seem to be correct. It says "Compatible with all incandescent and most dimmable CFL/LED bulbs".